# SharePoint Online - Is it possible to provide custom formatting for Highlighted Content webpart List Layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, highlighted-content-web-part

I am trying to get the recent updates across sites -i.e. content roll up.

By configuring the webpart, I do get the desired results in list format.

However, is it possible to apply custom formatting to that layout ?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box **Highlighted content web part** does not support custom JSON formatting.

You can only Choose either of default layout: Grid, List, Filmstrip, or Carousel.

However there is a SPFx web part sample, developed by community members which supports custom HTML templates.

You can find it at: [Content Query web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-content-query-online)

Comment: You might want to change the link to the webpart though. Its giving page not found.

Comment: Thanks, corrected the link. Autocorrect/suggestions changed the URL while copy pasting :(

Comment: All good :) Thanks !